# Удаление файлов по условию python

Tags: python

Есть список в файле `del.csv` который содержащий имена файлов, в таком виде:

```
"/usr/local/folder/reports/reports-04010/201603/7991982.pdf"
"/usr/local/folder/reports/reports-04010/201603/7991983.pdf"
"/usr/local/folder/reports/reports-04010/201603/7991985.pdf"
```

Необходимо удалить все файлы из `/usr/local/folder/`, которых нет в списке

Пока идея заключается в том что бы получить список файлов через `os.listdir`, сравнить его с файлом, и удалять файлы по списку из полученного дифа.

Может есть какие то более простые пути решения данной задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os

for_deletion = {i.strip() for i in open('del.csv')}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/usr/local/folder/'):
    for name in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, name)
        if path in for_deletion:
            os.remove(path)
```